# PLSQL code requirement for partition comparison in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way to compare values for one partition with another partition of the same table? Requirement is like I have a table and suppose there are 5 partitions, table having two columns(not null). Suppose Col1 having all the distinct values and in col2 there can be a duplicate values. So while comparing one partition with other or we can say rest of the 4 partitions on the basis of distinct col2 values according to the partition name, if the value match between two partition then a new table will create with union of the two partition.

And if there is no match between the col2 values of one partition and with rest of the partition then new table will create of same structure(without any union).
Note: 
I want to automate this process through PLSQL code.

Currently what I am doing manually:

I have one table having five partition, for example Table structure:

```
 create table PART_TEST1
 (col1 int not null, 
 col2 int not null)
 partition by range (col2)
 (partition part1 values less than (10),
 partition part2 values less than (20),
 partition part3 values less than (30),
 partition part4 values less than (40),
 partition part5 values less than (maxvalue));
```

Data distribution:

- `col1` having distinct values like- 1, 2, 3....so on.
- `col2` having values like- 1, 2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1...so on

`col2` has duplicate values and my goal is to find the distinct values according to the name of the partition like:

```
select distinct col2 from PART_TEST1 partition (part1);
```

For example output of above query is:

```
Col2
1
2
```

Again I am querying for finding matching values in other partition:

```
select distinct col2 from PART_TEST1 partition (part2);
```

For example output of above query is:

```
Col2
2
3
```

So now part 1 and part2 has one same value '2' and two non common values 1 and 3.
so my final query is:

```
create table 'TABLE_NAME' as select * from part_test1 where col2 = 1;

create table 'TABLE_NAME' as select * from part_test1 where col2 = 3;

create table 'TABLE_NAME' as 
(select * from part_test1 where col2 = 2
union
select * from part_test1 where col2 = 2);
```

Hopefully now you will get some clarity about my problem. I am new to PLSQL and not able to compare the partition values. Also if I am able to compare the values then how can I store the output of the comparison query and then finally create the table? And also I am thinking that I need to compare one partition with rest of the partition like some kind of loop operation.

Comment: Please show some example table data.  This is too hard to understand.  Are your talking about Oracle Partitioned tables

Comment: The answer to your question probably involves `CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS SELECT...`, but what the `SELECT` would be is impossible to determine given the limited information you've provided. Please edit your question and add further details. Thanks.